# SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: sql-server-2012, laravel-5.4

Please tell me how to solve this problem
i am connecting laravel 5.4 with sql server.After all the settings in config/database.php and .env.When i am writing this command php artisan migrate on cmd.it shows following error

Comment: That error often indicates the port (1433 default) is blocked by a firewall. Try testing port connectivity using `telnet` or this powershell command from a command-prompt: `powershell -Command echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Client.Connect('YourServer', 1433)) 'success'`